# how to mix template expression syntax with code

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-directives, angular-template

My first Angular 2 project. Simple rolling total on a table. Someone here suggested doing this using a method like so {{calcRollingtotal(..)}}. But then as I got deeper in Angular I realized I can do with template expression but struggling with syntax. Please help. So far I have below but below not working .Tried various combinations..

```
<table border="1">
   <tr *ngFor="let sales of salesDataArray;let i = index">
     <td> {{( i > 0) ? 
                       salesDataArray[i-1].fiscalPeriod + 
                       salesDataArray[i].fiscalPeriod} 
                     : 
                       salesDataArray[i].fiscalPeriod}
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `*ngFor="let i = index"` what are you looping through ? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: what you're trying to achieve, bit unclear here.

Comment: looping thru an array. However accessing the underlying array with an index (i) instead of the object .. sales in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3b7tam) to visualize the answer.

To avoid confusion and make your code more readable the simpliest solution is to use two separate elements in combination with `*ngIf`.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let item of salesDataArray; let i = index">
    <td>
      <ng-container *ngIf="i > 0">
        {{salesDataArray[i-1].fiscalPeriod + item.fiscalPeriod}}
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="i === 0">
        {{item.fiscalPeriod}}
      </ng-container>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using `ng-container` ensures that the element is not stamped in the DOM, so that the code results in something like `<td>5</td>`.

Note that `item` is equivalent to `salesDataArray[i]` in this case.

More elegant solution ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-haf1sm)):

```
<table border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let item of salesDataArray; let i = index">
    <td>
      {{( i > 0) ? (salesDataArray[i-1].fiscalPeriod + salesDataArray[i].fiscalPeriod) : (salesDataArray[i].fiscalPeriod)}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you the man. I think this will do it for me. I was just hoping for something more elegant :-). Will mark as answer after I try it out. Thanks

Comment: Check the update on my answer for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Works like a champ. Side note. Lately I have been getting lot of help here. Used stack for many years in the past and then gave up and went to msdn forums when people here got very snobbish when basic questions were asked. Nice to see stack overflow like the way it was many years ago.